# changing skins in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

hello im making game and im trying to add skins for layers in this game so i made a vovieclip
and inside it there are skins http://prntscr.com/2as4mp and inside that when it be clicked there are http://prntscr.com/2as4pm i want it that when i ress this button the skin will change in the menu i tried this

```
select_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, open1243)
function open1243(event:MouseEvent){
bk = 1
gotoAndStop(2) 

}
stop ();
```

well that dint work um where there is goandsto 2 that goes to menu thats it nothing works pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event listener, you're not specifying that you want `select_2` to `gotoAndStop`, rather, it will apply that method call to whatever `this` is in the scope of that method. I'm guessing, at that point, it's the `stage`.

```
select_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, open1243);
function open1243(event:MouseEvent){
    bk = 1
    select_2.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

You should probably make sure your event listener could be used for any object similar to `select_2`, in which case, I would suggest you change that line of code to:

```
    MovieClip(event.target).gotoAndStop(2)
```

Comment: it dont work you know that 2ndcity is in moviecli in frame 2 that code dont work what can i use instead of ot and for the jet part what codes i use

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just read your comment about 5 times, and I really don't understand what you're saying/asking. Is there anything I can help further with?